# Using the definition of derivative to prove $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)^{-1} = -f(x)^{-2} \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$

Tags: calculus

> How do I prove that the L.H.S = R.H.S
>
> $$ \frac{d}{dx} f(x)^{-1} = -f(x)^{-2} \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$$

I started by using the first principles using substition i.e. making $f(x)=u$ so $g(u)=u^{-1}$ and then coming to the conclusion:

$$\frac{d}{du} g(u) = \frac{-1}{u^2}$$

After this I don't know what to do.

Comment: Both sides are only defined for all $x$ such that $f(x)\ne0$.

Comment: Apply the chain rule. In your derivation you forgot the "inner derivative".

Answer (score 3):

By using the definition of derivative:
$$\begin{split} 
\frac{d}{dx} f(x)^{-1}
&=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}(\frac{1}{f(x+h)}-\frac{1}{f(x)}) \\
&=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(x+h)}{hf(x)f(x+h)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}*\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{-1}{f(x)f(x+h)}\\
&=\frac{-1}{f(x)^2}\frac{d}{dx} f(x)
\end{split}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the well known formula

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac uv )=\frac{1}{v^2}(v\frac{du}{dx}-u\frac{dv}{dx})$$

with $u=1$ and $v=f$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the chain rule, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}$, and then substitute back.